# Objects disappearing from Xcode Object Library Palette

Tags: ios, xcode, api, object

I am relatively new to iPhone development.

When I open Xcode, my object library palette contains an `"Address Book People Picker View"` and other objects that disappear when I select a `.xib` file.  This seems to be consistent with the behavior mentioned here: [XCode Developer API - Object Library - Objects Disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371482/xcode-developer-api-object-library-objects-disappearing)

The above answer suggests that the `Xcode` palette is initially populated with all `iOS` and Mac objects, but then amends the list appropriate to the target when the `XIB` file is selected.  I thought that the `AddressBook` framework/objects were supported in `iOS` so if only `iOS` objects remain then why are the `AddressBook` objects disappearing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW I have added the AddressBook and AddressBookUI framework to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use the `AddresBookUi` framework objects in Interface Builder, but must instantiate them programmatically.  Some of them used in specific ways to function correctly, for example ABUnknownPersonViewController must be  embedded in a navigation controller.

Since many of these views cannot be used in a generic fashion they are not exposed in interface builder to prevent confusing users.

For example:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self   presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```